# connect to socket server on button click using net nodejs module

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, electron, esp8266

I'm developing an electron app for controlling an ESP8266 relay over TCP.
The ESP8266 has a TCP server running on port 8080 on my local network.
The basic code bellow works. The ESP8266 accepts the connection and commands for turning on/off the relay also work.

```
const electron = require('electron')
var net = require('net');

var HOST = '192.168.0.33';
var PORT = 8080;

var socket = new net.Socket();

socket.connect(PORT, HOST, function() {
  console.log('CONNECTED TO: ' + HOST + ':' + PORT);    
});
```

But now I would like to make this connection "socket.connect" on the push of a button in my electron app so I can change the IP address if needed using an input field. Otherwise the IP address is hardcoded.

The following code does not work:

```
const electron = require('electron')    
var net = require('net');

const turnOn = new Buffer([0xA0, 0x01, 0x00, 0xA1]);
const turnOff = new Buffer([0xA0, 0x01, 0x01, 0xA2]);

var socket = new net.Socket();

const connectBtn = document.getElementById('connectBtn');
const onBtn = document.getElementById('onBtn');
const offBtn = document.getElementById('offBtn');

connectBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  console.log("clicked connect");
  var ipAddress = document.getElementById('ipAddress').value;
  var port = document.getElementById('port').value;    
  socket.connect(port, ipAddress, function() {
    console.log('CONNECTED TO: ' + ipAddress + ':' + port);    
  });
})
```

In other words. If I put "socket.connect" outside the Connect button click event, my app connects to ESP8266. 
If I put "socket.connect" inside Connect button click event, the connection does not happen.

Is there another way of changing the IP address if needed at runtime?

This is a screenshot of the app I'm trying to build:
[image]

Comment: A possible scope problem. So u want to get your pc ip addr via client code?

Comment: I want to connect to a TCP server running on an ESP8266. ESP8266 IP address can change, that's why there is an input field. My PC IP address does not matter in this case. 

It seems like the event socket.connect(port, ipAddress) does not happen while I'm pressing the Connect button. But it works outside the button press event.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the Socket host is ip instead of the domain, I have the same problem. Maybe this is the bug of Electron. Upgrading to electron3.0, and Socket.connect is fixed.

Comment: Upgrading to electron 3 worked!
Now I can have socket.connect inside button click event and therefore can change IP dynamically.
Thanks Raidou!